# How to override multiple filters query in sonata admin

Tags: php, symfony, filter, sonata-admin, sonata

I am using sonata admin to set up an admin class with four filters. These filters are multiple choice and related to other entities. I want to make these filters dependent and run one filter query to filter the data considering all selected filter values. So far I just used sonata callback filter, but it can not filter when I select two or three fields to filter data. Is there a technique to override the query sonata run for filters?

```
$datagridMapper
        ->add('campaign', null, array(), 'entity', array(
          'class'       => 'AppPolioDbBundle:Campaign',
          'choice_label' => 'campaignName', 'multiple' => true,
          'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->groupBy('u.campaignName');
   },
          ))
        ->add('region', 'doctrine_orm_callback', array(
            'callback'   => array($this, 'callbackFilterRegion'),
            'field_type' => 'checkbox'
          ),
          'choice',
          array('choices' => $this -> getRegionList(), 'multiple' => true))

            ->add('district.districtCode', null, array(), 'entity', array(
             'class'       => 'AppPolioDbBundle:District',
             'choice_label' => 'districtName', 'multiple' => true,
             'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
               return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
               ->groupBy('u.districtName');
      },

             ))
```

Comment: could you show some code please

Comment: @PeterPopelyskho I have edited the question and added the codes.